# How to reach a user that has a name with disallowed content?

Tags: support

I tried to comment to [this user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32558/ciro-santilli-%E5%85%AD%E5%9B%9B%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6-%E6%B3%95%E8%BD%AE%E5%8A%9F-%E7%BA%B3%E7%B1%B3%E6%AF%94%E4%BA%9A-%E5%A8%81%E8%A7%86), trying to ask why he left non-commented links in comments, that were links to the question itself.

I got the message `Comments cannot contain that content`:

[image]

After rewording and rewording I noticed this is because of the content of the user's name that gets inserted by typing  <kbd>@</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

How can I comment to this user without using the (blocked) full name in a way that he will be notified of being addressed?

For now I flagged the link-only comments, that are without any explanation, as non-constructive. But I rather ask the poster for an explanation of intentions and potentially improve his commenting behaviour.

Comment: Another question is why [se] allows a name to be set to this kind of text if I am not allowed to use that text to address the person. If that content is offending in some way, it is still showing up beneath questions.

Comment: You can use the three first characters: "Cir". You're welcome. You can also use "CiroSantilli" for the maximum extent possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably, the links are relevant to what the OP is asking. I let them stay, there might be some useful info there. As for the other bit, you don't need to `@` the user if your comment is right under theirs, they will be notified anyway (I think).

Also, you should be able to `@` ping the user with the 1st three letters of their name. All of these should work:

```
@cir
@ciro
@ciros
@cirosantilli
```

As for why, that's probably because Chinese and Korean characters [are blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263725/203101) due to excessive spam in those languages. I know that's the case for titles, it seems to be so for comments as well.

Comment: The [first link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9099/#comment384646_9099) is a link to the question itself, so it is implicitly  relevant, but also useless and irritating, because you can't see that self reference without following the link. I tried @ciro and see if there is a reaction

Comment: @Anthon oh, I hadn't realized (which nicely proves your point). Still, some of the others are presumably relevant.

Comment: Writing `@ciro` worked, the explanation was that the same three links were inserted in other comments as well.